# How to make this imagemagick command work correctly?

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick

```
# create a 2 color image from scratch to supply colors for mapping
$ convert -size 10x10 xc:white -fill red -draw 'rectangle 0 0 5 5' \
    -colors 2 +dither bicolor.gif
# map 'em, Danno!
$ convert -colors 2 -normalize +dither -remap bicolor.gif in.png out.png
```

The first command doesn't work.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using single quotes double quotes need to be used, then it works.

Comment: That sounds... wrong...